# How do I monitor bash_history file for manual modifications?

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, inotify

I am trying to create a daemon to monitor a users's *bash_history* file for manual modifications. In other words, if a user opens the file and modifies it, the daemon will notify this action for safety measures, but when the history updates itself, nothing happens.

The solution I tried is using [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait):

```
while true; do
    inotifywait -e close_write,move,delete ~/.bash_history && notify
done
```

where *notify* is a script that will do a specific notification procedure.

I believe this would work fine for most of files, but in this case it doesn't, since *notify* is executed every time the history updates.

Is it possible this way, or should I use another application?

Comment: I doubt this will be possible. How could the system know whether a user or an automated process opened the file? In both cases, the file was opened.

Comment: I'm not familiar with System Tap, but could it or something similar be used to check what process opened the file?
As an aside, you may like to check out this link about trying to [prevent users from editing their history files](http://mewbies.com/how_to_disable_bash_history_or_limit_tutorial.html#09)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with `inotify`. There is no configuration that could probe if a file is altered by an user or a process, neither if it will monitor only "append to files".

And ***EVEN if there exists*** one "append to file" inotify event, one user could inject `bash_history` data with `echo >>` creating bogus entries and losing all the meaning of your monitoring.

You could harden your history files by following this advice, and i think this is the best you could do:

- [Secured bash history usage](https://superuser.com/a/308892/210242)

Comment: I see. In addition, I believe it's possible to instead of monitoring the history specifically, it would be better to watch whenever root logs in or sudo is used for superuser privileges. And if the bash history is secured, it could be possible to retrieve which commands were used.

Comment: Or, make bash use `syslog` and replicate the logs to a remote server. This could be more useful than creating local locks to local `bash_history` files